# Access SMS Sent Message

Tags: android, sms

Is there a way to access the sent message of the receiver?
I'm using smsmanager on android to sent message to a certain number and my objective now is that I'll create a method that will confirm me that the receiver has receive the message and show me what message he/she received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sms type constants**

```
MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL    = 0;
MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX  = 1;
MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT   = 2;
MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT  = 3;
MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX = 4;
MESSAGE_TYPE_FAILED = 5; // for failed outgoing messages
MESSAGE_TYPE_QUEUED = 6; // for messages to send later
```

use `MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT=2` with condition

so use following code :

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                                    "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
            Log.e("Count",count);
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
                String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
                if(type.equals("2")) // 2 for Sent Sms
                 {
                String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                }
            }
        }
```

You also need Following Permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: thanks for that tarsem :) I'll update you later after I've study your code

Comment: Oh I forgot i didn't mean sent message i mean the inbox of the receiver... is this applicable to that? sorry

Comment: @RonPelayo yes change if(type.equals("2")) to if(type.equals("1"))

Comment: and last question i think your code is .. it will access your own phone... how can i access the receivers phone like

if I send the message on 12345678 I'll access that device inbox

Comment: @RonPelayo i don't know about that ! i think its not possible directly !

Answer (score 1):

Register a content observer.

```
SMSObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSObserver( new Handler() );
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/out"), true, smsSentObserver);


public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver
{

    public SMSObserver(Handler handler) {
       super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        querySMS();
    }
}

protected void querySMS() {
    Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/out");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToNext(); // this will make it point to the first record, which is the last SMS sent
    String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")); //content of sms
    String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")); //phone num
    String time = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date")); //date
    String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol")); //protocol
    int type = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type")));


}
```

Comment: thanks for that Tarun :) I'll update you later after I've study your code

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i using for the similar function, hope it helps.

```
        public class OutgoingSms {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ContentResolver contentResolver;
        ContentObserver contentObserver;
        String senderNum;
        String message;
        String type;
        String smsContent;

        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, contentObserver);
        contentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Uri smsURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
            String[] strings = {"address", "body"};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(smsURI, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToNext();
            senderNum = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
            message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
            type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
            if (type.equals("2"))
              {
            smsContent = "send sms to " + senderNum + " content is " + message1;
            sms.sendTextMessage("+123456789", null, smsContent, null, null);
             }
        }
      }
    };
```